# Search broken in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search, error

Search in SharePoint throws an error, `NullReferenceException`, whether using the Search box on a normal page or even just loading the Advanced Search page.

I was originally getting `System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException` and Round Robin Service Load Balancer `EndpointFailure` errors in the SharePoint ULS logs whenever I tried to search.  I examined IIS and determined that the Web Apps existed.  I stopped and started the Search Query and Site Settings Serviec on the server.  That was the last I saw of the `EndpointFailure` and `ServerTooBusyException` errors.

However, a new error showed up.  This time is was a `System.NullReferenceException` from `SetPropertiesOnQueryReader()` at `CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit()`.  KB Article 976462 looked promising, until further research showed that it adds the **AllowInsecureTransport** property in the **SecurityBindingElement** class, and changes the value from its default of *False* to *True*.  However, this property exists and is already set to *True* in my environment.

I found [this same problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/sharepoint-2010-error-when-searching-in-coreresultswebpartoninit), however deleting the Search Service Apps and Proxies, recreating them and performing an `IISRESET` did not fix my problem.

When the Advanced Enterprise Search page is brought up, an error is returned to the screen: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

This is the log entry out of the ULS:

> CoreResultsWebPart::OnInit: Exception initializing: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>
> Internal server error exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e)

Answer (score 3):

I have had a very similar issue this week and I've just resolved it. The logs looked much the same with null references but the front-end trouble occured as the enterprise search template showing a 'could not connect to search service' issue. The search service was running and previously worked fine...

In any case, I was in a position where I could nuke my search subsite and start again. Which I did but still had the same issue. Tried recreating the search app but still no-go. So I deleted the search application and created one with a new name, put a new enterprise search site over it and now my problem is solved...

Hope this is relevant/suitable to your requirements and helps you past this b*@%&%d of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Couldnt agree more with @Foocode.

1. Nuke the site.
2. Delete the Search Application.
3. Check the Index drive - this is where u may have some issue - if the old index doesnt remove due to some corruption / damage. You may have to resort to hard removal.
4. Setup the Search Foundation Search first - if you already havent
5. Setup Search App

Answer (score 1):

I had same kind of issues and we solved it using

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | where {$_.Name -eq “DatabaseName”}

$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()
```

Reference for details: https://synkventures.com/2017/01/28/sharepoint-2013-search-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-fix-sharepoint-sharepointsearch/